# Issue displaying on Adafruit display when enabling GSM communication

Tags: adafruit, mkr1000

I am trying to write to the adafruit display using Arduino MKR1500 when it is connected to the internet. The issue I am facing is when I add the code to connect to the cloud, the display stops working. If I removed that piece of code, the display outputs correctly.
As of now I am just printing "hello world" on the screen.
Below is the code without the cloud connection:

```
/**************************************************************************
  This is a library for several Adafruit displays based on ST77* drivers.

  Works with the Adafruit 1.8" TFT Breakout w/SD card
    ----> http://www.adafruit.com/products/358
  The 1.8" TFT shield
    ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/802
  The 1.44" TFT breakout
    ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/2088
  The 1.14" TFT breakout
  ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/4383
  The 1.3" TFT breakout
  ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/4313
  The 1.54" TFT breakout
    ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/3787
  The 2.0" TFT breakout
    ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/4311
  as well as Adafruit raw 1.8" TFT display
    ----> http://www.adafruit.com/products/618

  Check out the links above for our tutorials and wiring diagrams.
  These displays use SPI to communicate, 4 or 5 pins are required to
  interface (RST is optional).

  Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code,
  please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing
  products from Adafruit!

  Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada for Adafruit Industries.
  MIT license, all text above must be included in any redistribution
 **************************************************************************/
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h> // Hardware-specific library for ST7735
#include <Adafruit_ST7789.h> // Hardware-specific library for ST7789
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Bounce2.h> // https://github.com/thomasfredericks/Bounce2
//#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <FlashStorage.h>


#if defined(ARDUINO_FEATHER_ESP32) // Feather Huzzah32
#define TFT_CS         14
#define TFT_RST        15
#define TFT_DC         32

#elif defined(ESP8266)
#define TFT_CS         4
#define TFT_RST        16
#define TFT_DC         5

#else
// For the breakout board, you can use any 2 or 3 pins.
// These pins will also work for the 1.8" TFT shield.
#define TFT_CS        1 // D v25 changes to use pin 1 for CS in MKR1500
#define TFT_RST        -1 // Or set to -1 and connect to Arduino RESET pin // D v25 changes to use built in reset pinout in MKR1500
#define TFT_DC         2 // D v25 changes to use pin 2 for CS in MKR1500
#endif


//D v15 for audrino to connect to fingerprint sensor
//D v2
#if (defined(__AVR__) || defined(ESP8266)) && !defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
// For UNO and others without hardware serial, we must use software serial...
// pin #2 is IN from sensor (GREEN wire)
// pin #3 is OUT from arduino  (WHITE wire)
// Set up the serial port to use softwareserial..
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 4);

#else
// On Leonardo/M0/etc, others with hardware serial, use hardware serial!
// #0 is green wire, #1 is white
#define mySerial Serial1

#endif



// OPTION 1 (recommended) is to use the HARDWARE SPI pins, which are unique
// to each board and not reassignable. For Arduino Uno: MOSI = pin 11 and
// SCLK = pin 13. This is the fastest mode of operation and is required if
// using the breakout board's microSD card.

// For 1.44" and 1.8" TFT with ST7735 use:
//Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST); // D v21 uncomment this and comment the line below to use 1.44inch display.Need to change the display font in case I use 1.44"

// For 1.14", 1.3", 1.54", and 2.0" TFT with ST7789:
Adafruit_ST7789 tft = Adafruit_ST7789(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST); // D v22 uncommment to use this display


#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <MKRNB.h>

// Debug options
#define PRINT_AT        true   // Show or hide AT command output from the modem

// PIN Number
const char PINNUMBER[]     = "";
char apn[] = "soracom.io";
char user[] = "sora";
char pass[] = "sora";

// Server details
const char server[] = "unified.soracom.io";
const int  port = 80;


NBClient client;
GPRS gprs;
NB nbAccess(PRINT_AT);
HttpClient http(client, server, port);

// connection state
  bool connected = false;

// Publish interval
long previousMillis = 0;
long interval = 1000; // milliseconds // D v2orginial value: long interval = 20000; chnages the time interval in which it will report



void setup(void) {

  // tft.initR(INITR_144GREENTAB); // Init ST7735R chip, green tab

  // OR use this initializer (uncomment) if using a 1.3" or 1.54" 240x240 TFT:
  tft.init(240, 240);           // Init ST7789 240x240  // D v22 uncommment to use this display

  // tft print function!
  tftPrintTest();

  pinMode(SARA_RESETN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SARA_RESETN, LOW);
  pinMode(SARA_PWR_ON, OUTPUT);
 
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //D v33
  /*while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }*/
 
  start_and_connect_modem();
 
  }

 void loop() {
  tft.invertDisplay(true);
  delay(500);


  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_GREEN);
  tft.setCursor(0, 10);
   
    tft.setCursor(0, 0);
    tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);

    tft.println("hello world");

   
    }



void tftPrintTest() {
  tft.setRotation(3);
  tft.setTextWrap(true);
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_GREEN);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
}
```

Below is the code with the cloud connection added

```
/**************************************************************************
  This is a library for several Adafruit displays based on ST77* drivers.

  Works with the Adafruit 1.8" TFT Breakout w/SD card
    ----> http://www.adafruit.com/products/358
  The 1.8" TFT shield
    ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/802
  The 1.44" TFT breakout
    ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/2088
  The 1.14" TFT breakout
  ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/4383
  The 1.3" TFT breakout
  ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/4313
  The 1.54" TFT breakout
    ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/3787
  The 2.0" TFT breakout
    ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/4311
  as well as Adafruit raw 1.8" TFT display
    ----> http://www.adafruit.com/products/618

  Check out the links above for our tutorials and wiring diagrams.
  These displays use SPI to communicate, 4 or 5 pins are required to
  interface (RST is optional).

  Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code,
  please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing
  products from Adafruit!

  Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada for Adafruit Industries.
  MIT license, all text above must be included in any redistribution
 **************************************************************************/
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h> // Hardware-specific library for ST7735
#include <Adafruit_ST7789.h> // Hardware-specific library for ST7789
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Bounce2.h> // https://github.com/thomasfredericks/Bounce2
//#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <FlashStorage.h>


#if defined(ARDUINO_FEATHER_ESP32) // Feather Huzzah32
#define TFT_CS         14
#define TFT_RST        15
#define TFT_DC         32

#elif defined(ESP8266)
#define TFT_CS         4
#define TFT_RST        16
#define TFT_DC         5

#else
// For the breakout board, you can use any 2 or 3 pins.
// These pins will also work for the 1.8" TFT shield.
#define TFT_CS        1 // D v25 changes to use pin 1 for CS in MKR1500
#define TFT_RST        -1 // Or set to -1 and connect to Arduino RESET pin // D v25 changes to use built in reset pinout in MKR1500
#define TFT_DC         2 // D v25 changes to use pin 2 for CS in MKR1500
#endif


//D v15 for audrino to connect to fingerprint sensor
//D v2
#if (defined(__AVR__) || defined(ESP8266)) && !defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
// For UNO and others without hardware serial, we must use software serial...
// pin #2 is IN from sensor (GREEN wire)
// pin #3 is OUT from arduino  (WHITE wire)
// Set up the serial port to use softwareserial..
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 4);

#else
// On Leonardo/M0/etc, others with hardware serial, use hardware serial!
// #0 is green wire, #1 is white
#define mySerial Serial1

#endif



// OPTION 1 (recommended) is to use the HARDWARE SPI pins, which are unique
// to each board and not reassignable. For Arduino Uno: MOSI = pin 11 and
// SCLK = pin 13. This is the fastest mode of operation and is required if
// using the breakout board's microSD card.

// For 1.44" and 1.8" TFT with ST7735 use:
//Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST); // D v21 uncomment this and comment the line below to use 1.44inch display.Need to change the display font in case I use 1.44"

// For 1.14", 1.3", 1.54", and 2.0" TFT with ST7789:
Adafruit_ST7789 tft = Adafruit_ST7789(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST); // D v22 uncommment to use this display


#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <MKRNB.h>

// Debug options
#define PRINT_AT        true   // Show or hide AT command output from the modem

// PIN Number
const char PINNUMBER[]     = "";
char apn[] = "soracom.io";
char user[] = "sora";
char pass[] = "sora";

// Server details
const char server[] = "unified.soracom.io";
const int  port = 80; 


NBClient client;
GPRS gprs;
NB nbAccess(PRINT_AT);
HttpClient http(client, server, port);

// connection state
  bool connected = false;

// Publish interval
long previousMillis = 0; 
long interval = 1000; // milliseconds // D v2orginial value: long interval = 20000; chnages the time interval in which it will report



void setup(void) {

  // tft.initR(INITR_144GREENTAB); // Init ST7735R chip, green tab

  // OR use this initializer (uncomment) if using a 1.3" or 1.54" 240x240 TFT:
  tft.init(240, 240);           // Init ST7789 240x240  // D v22 uncommment to use this display

  // tft print function!
  tftPrintTest();

  pinMode(SARA_RESETN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SARA_RESETN, LOW);
  pinMode(SARA_PWR_ON, OUTPUT);
  
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //D v33
  /*while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }*/
  
  start_and_connect_modem();
 
  }

 void loop() {
  tft.invertDisplay(true);
  delay(500);


  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_GREEN);
  tft.setCursor(0, 10);
    
    tft.setCursor(0, 0);
    tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);

    tft.println("hello world");

    
    }



void tftPrintTest() {
  tft.setRotation(3);
  tft.setTextWrap(true);
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_GREEN);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
}


void post_data(String postData) {
 //Serial.println("making POST request");
  String contentType = "application/json";

  http.post("/", contentType, postData);

  // read the status code and body of the response
  int statusCode = http.responseStatusCode();
  String response = http.responseBody();

  /*Serial.print("Status code: ");
  Serial.println(statusCode);
  Serial.print("Response: ");
  Serial.println(response);*/

}

void start_and_connect_modem(){
  pinMode(SARA_RESETN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SARA_RESETN, LOW);
  pinMode(SARA_PWR_ON, OUTPUT);
  
  // Send Poweron pulse
  digitalWrite(SARA_PWR_ON, HIGH);
  delay(150);
  digitalWrite(SARA_PWR_ON, LOW);
  delay(500);
  // Turn on the modem
  if (Serial) Serial.print(">>> Turning on modem...");
  if (MODEM.begin()) {
    if (Serial) Serial.println(" done!");
  } else {
    if (Serial) Serial.println(" error, could not turn on modem! Try power-cycling.");
    return;
  }

  while (!MODEM.noop());
  MODEM.sendf("ATI9");
  MODEM.waitForResponse(2000);
  
  // Run AT commands to reset the modem to global default settings
  Serial.print(">>> Resetting modem to default settings...");
  MODEM.sendf("AT+CFUN=0");
  MODEM.waitForResponse(6000);
  MODEM.sendf("AT+UMNOPROF=2");
  MODEM.waitForResponse(2000);
  MODEM.sendf("AT+CFUN=15");
  MODEM.waitForResponse(6000);
  MODEM.sendf("AT+CFUN=0");
  MODEM.waitForResponse(2000);
  MODEM.sendf("AT+UMNOPROF=0");
  MODEM.waitForResponse(2000);
  MODEM.sendf("AT+CFUN=15");
  MODEM.waitForResponse(2000);
  MODEM.sendf("AT+URAT=7");
  MODEM.waitForResponse(2000);
  //D v33
  /*MODEM.sendf("AT+UBANDMASK?");
  MODEM.waitForResponse(6000);*/
  Serial.println(" done!");
  
  delay(2000);
  // attempt to connect to GSM and GPRS:
  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to GSM and GPRS");
  //Serial.println();
  connect_modem();
  
}

void connect_modem(){
  // After starting the modem with GSM.begin()
  // attach the shield to the GPRS network with the APN, login and password
  while (!connected) {
    if ((nbAccess.begin(PINNUMBER, apn, user, pass) == NB_READY) &&
        (gprs.attachGPRS() == GPRS_READY)) {
      connected = true;
    } else {
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

  Serial.println("You're connected to the network");  
}
```

Can someone please let me know what I am missing?